# Slack - Interactive Message URL is not getting invoked

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack-api

I have enabled interactive component for my slack app with an URL from AWS API Gateway which triggers a lambda function. Whenever I click on the interactive component eg. button, I am not receiving POST request from slack.

Instead I get an error message on the slack window.

### Error

> Darn – that didn't work (error message: `400_client_error`). Manage the app at testApp.[image]

Comment: What else have you tried to debug this?  Have you for example CURLed it to see if that works, or if you get a more descriptive error?

Comment: @PaulWarren yeah, I tried to debug this, CURL is working, but slack button is not. no more descriptive error.

Answer (score 1):

Action URL will receive an HTTP POST request, including a `payload` body parameter, itself containing an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` JSON string.
I was trying to parse the request body as `JSON`

---

For reference: https://medium.com/@farski/learn-aws-api-gateway-with-the-slack-police-ca8d636e9fc0

Comment: I check the article, but it's not giving good answers. Is it working for you? Could you share your solution? 
Thanks!